# How do I create a link for a local html document to make it accessible online to anyone who has the link?

Tags: html, http

I have to create a website as an assignment (for school). The problem is that our professor never explained a thing about Html, CSS, or java so whatever I have done till now(,i.e., creating HTML pages using notes) is thanks to w3school. Now I have finished writing everything but I can't seem to figure out how to create a link between the various pages so that they are accessible to anyone as I have tried connecting them using  href="page2.html" but they are only accessible if I have all the files downloaded on my computer... How can I make them accessible to anyone who has the homepage link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you upload or give your homepage page (index.html) ,  make sure that you also upload other pages which you have created so that anyone can access the pages.